# Time complexity for an algorithm is ok?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I want to design an algorithm with `O(n(log(2)n)^2)` time complexity. I wrote this:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
 j=i;
 while(j != 1)
     j=j/2;

 j=i;
 while(j !=1)
     j=j/2;
}
```

Does it have O(n(log(2)n)^2) time complexity? If not, where I am going wrong and how can I fix it so that its time complexity is `O(n(log(2)n)^2)`?

Comment: Your algorithm has `O(N * 2 * log N)` which is `O(N * log N)`

Comment: It seems that the obvious thing to do would be a loop that iterates from 0 to (n*log(n))^2.

Comment: there are 3 products in your expression, this implies you need 3 nested loops the first O(n) and the second and third O(log(n))

Comment: Also note that all logs are proportional to each other so there's no need to be explicit about the base of the log. O(log2(n)) = O(log(n))

Comment: An algorithm should have some kind of output. Since the results of this calculation are discarded, it could be optimized away completely. As such, this algo has O(1) time complexity in practice. Of course since O(1) is included in O(n(log n)^2) you have succeeded anyway: Big-O notation is only a *maximum bound* for complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Slight digression:

As the guys said in the comments, the algorithm is indeed `O(n log n)`. This is coincidentally identical to the result obtained by multiplying the complexity of the inner loop by the outer loop, i.e. `O(log i) x O(n)`.

This may lead you to believe that we can simply add another iteration of the inner loop to obtain the `(log n)`<sup>2</sup> part:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    int k = i;
    while (k >= 1)
        k /= 2;
        int j = i;
        while (j >= 1)
            j /= 2;
    }
}
```

But let's look at how the original complexity is derived:

[image]

(Using Sterling's approximation)

Therefore the proposed modification would give:

[image]

Which is not what we want.

---

An example I can think of from a recent personal project is *semi-naive KD-tree construction*. The pseudocode is given below:

```
def kd_recursive_cons (list_points):
    if length(list_points) < predefined_threshold:
        return new leaf(list_points)

    A <- random axis (X, Y, Z)
    sort list_points by their A-coordinate

    mid <- find middle element in list_points
    list_L, list_R <- split list_points at mid

    node_L <- kd_recursive_cons(list_L)
    node_R <- kd_recursive_cons(list_R)

    return new node (node_L, node_R)
end
```

The time complexity function is therefore given by:

[image]

Where the `n log n` part is from sorting. We can obviously ignore the `Dn` linear part, and also the constant `C`. Thus:

[image]

Which is what we wanted.

---

Now to write a simpler piece of code with the same time complexity. We can make use of the summation we obtained in the above derivation...

[image]

And noting that the parameter passed to the `log` function is divided by two in every loop, we can thus write the code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (int k = n; k >= 1; k /= 2) {
        int j = k;
        while (j >= 1)
            j /= 2;
    }
}
```

This looks like the "naive" but incorrect solution mentioned at the beginning, with the difference being that the nested loops there had different bounds (`j` did not depend on `k`, but `k` depended on `i` instead of directly on `n`).

---

EDIT: some numerical tests to confirm that the complexity is as intended:

Test function code:

```
int T(int n) {
    int o = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = n; j >= 1; j /= 2)
            for (int k = j; k >= 1; k /= 2, o++);
    return o;
}
```

Numerical results:

```
n          T(n)
-------------------
2           3
4           18
8           70
16          225
32          651
64          1764
128         4572
256         11475
512         28105
1024        67518
2048        159666
4096        372645
8192        860055
16384       1965960
32768       4456312
65536       10026855
131072      22413141
262144      49807170
524288      110100270
```

Then I plotted `sqrt(T(n) / n)` against `n`. If the complexity is correct this should give a `log(n)` graph, or a *straight line* if plotted with a log-scale horizontal axis.

And this is indeed what we get:

[image]